# Py.test won't find tests

Tags: python, pytest

I'm using `pytest`, but in this project, the tests are in the regular modules, not modules labeled `test_stuff.py`

I tried to [change the test discovery](http://pytest.org/latest/example/pythoncollection.html#changing-standard-python-test-discovery) by adding a `pytest.ini` file in the root of my project with the following contents:

```
[pytest]
python_files = *.py
python_functions=test_*
```

When I run the tests, still nothing is found:

```
$ py.test
================================ test session starts ================================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.6 -- py-1.4.20 -- pytest-2.5.2
collected 0 items 

=================================  in 0.03 seconds ==================================
```

My layout could hardly be simpler:

```
$ ls
foo.py
pytest.ini
```

Where `foo.py` contains:

```
def add(a, b):
    return a+b

def test_add():
    assert 4 == add(2, 2)
```

Comment: @jonrsharpe Expect it isn't picking up the `.ini`, that's kind of the point. I've added details.

Comment: it seems according to the documantation the classes are being collected and not the functions http://pytest.org/latest/customize.html#confval-python_classes

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't see how your example differs from mine. Same result.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm sorry, I had forgotten to hit 'save edits'. My example is there now.

Comment: Setting the `so_test` directory up exactly as yours is, `foo.test_add` gets discovered; it's no-repro from me, perhaps someone with a closer setup to yours will be able to shed some light on it.

Comment: Upgrading fixed it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade!

```
$ sudo pip install pytest --upgrade
```

This setup works with pytest 2.8, fails with 2.5.

Comment: As for why: the glob syntax for `python_functions` and `python_classes` (rather than just `python_files`) was only introduced in v2.7.0 - see https://pytest.org/latest/announce/release-2.7.0.html#compared-to-2-6-4, https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/600